# Ansible with itertools cycle

Tags: python, loops, ansible, cycle

how i can get same results in ansible with loop?

I want to use

```
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}"
     loop: "{{ gs_hostname | product(wl_hostname) | list }}"
```

But i get:

> ok: [localhost] => {
> "msg": {
> "gs-01": "wl-01",
> "gs-02": "wl-02",
> "gs-03": null,
> "gs-04": null
> } }

What I expect:

```
from itertools import cycle

gs_hostname = ["gs01", "gs02", "gs03", "gs04"]
wl_hostname = ["wl01", "wl02"]

for a,b in zip(gs_hostname, cycle(wl_hostname)):
    print (a,b)
```

result:

> gs01 wl01 gs02 wl02 gs03 wl01 gs04 wl02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
      gs_hostname: [gs-01, gs-02, gs-03, gs-04, gs-05, gs-06, gs-07]
      wl_hostname: [wl-01, wl-02, wl-03]
  tasks:
    - debug:
         msg: "{% set wl_list = wl_hostname %}
               {% set row_class = cycler(* wl_list) %}
               {% for gs in gs_hostname %}{{ gs }} - {{ row_class.next() }}{% endfor %}"
```

More info [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#cycler).

Comment: Then you are maybe even better using the loop.cycle described there: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is nothing native in Ansible to achieve this, indeed.

This said, you can use a little bit of computing and a [modulo](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#math) coupled with the loop [`index_var`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#tracking-progress-through-a-loop-with-index-var) in order to achieve this.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no  
        
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} {{ wl_hostname[idx % wl_hostname | length] }}"
      loop: "{{ gs_hostname }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: idx
      vars:
        gs_hostname: 
          - gs01
          - gs02
          - gs03
          - gs04
        wl_hostname: 
          - wl01
          - wl02
```

This gives as output:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=gs01) => {
    "msg": "gs01 wl01"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=gs02) => {
    "msg": "gs02 wl02"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=gs03) => {
    "msg": "gs03 wl01"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=gs04) => {
    "msg": "gs04 wl02"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thenks you very mutch !!